# Submitting posts with attachments to phpbb by phpscript

Tags: php, phpbb

I want to submit a post to my phpbb forum with a phpscript.
Currently, I am using the submit_post() function in includes\functions_posting.php to correctly submit the text and subject of the post, but can't get my head around how to submit an attachment too. Currently, I'm saving the files to the rootfolder of the phpbb forum.
Subject, text and attachments are hexencrypted and passed by calling the phpscript by URL.
My Code:

```
    <?php
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
$phpbb_root_path = rootpath;
$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.') , 1);

include ($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);
include ($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_posting.' . $phpEx);

$user_id = userid;
$forum_id = forumid;
$subject = hex2bin(request_var('subject', ""));
$text = hex2bin(request_var('text', ""));
$attachmentNumber = request_var('number', 0);
$attachmentNameArray = [];
$attachmentDataArray = [];
for ($i=1; $i <= $attachmentNumber; $i++){
    $attachmentNameArray[$i] = hex2bin(request_var('name'.$i, ""));
    $attachmentDataArray[$i] = hex2bin(request_var('attachment'.$i, ""));
    file_put_contents($phpbb_root_path . filestoragefolder. $attachmentNameArray[$i], $attachmentDataArray[$i]);
}

$user->session_create($user_id);
$auth->acl($user->data);
$user->setup();

$sql = 'SELECT forum_name FROM ' . FORUMS_TABLE . ' WHERE forum_id=' . (int)$forum_id;
$result = $db->sql_query($sql);
$row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result);
$db->sql_freeresult($result);
$forum_name = $row['forum_name'];
//Submit the new post
$poll = $uid = $bitfield = $flags = '';
generate_text_for_storage($text, $uid, $bitfield, $flags, true, true, true);


$data = array( 
    'forum_id'      => $forum_id,
    'topic_id'       => 0,
    'icon_id'       => false,
    'enable_bbcode'     => true,
    'enable_smilies'    => true,
    'enable_urls'       => true,
    'enable_sig'        => true,
    'message'       => $text,
    'message_md5'   => md5($text),
    'bbcode_bitfield'   => $bitfield,
    'bbcode_uid'        => $uid,
    'post_edit_locked'  => 0,
    'topic_title'       => $subject,
    'notify_set'        => false,
    'notify'            => false,
    'post_time'         => 0,
    'forum_name'        => $forum_name,
    'enable_indexing'   => true,
    'force_approved_state'    => true,
    'force_visibility'            => true,
);

$result = submit_post('post', $subject, '', POST_NORMAL, $poll, $data);
if ($result===FALSE){
    echo "Error sending post";
}
else{
    echo "Post sent successfully, URL is: $result";
}

$user->session_kill(false);
?>
```

How can I simply submit attachments to posts? Ideally with the submit_post() function.
Thanks!